Why generator loss using BinaryCrossEntropy with from_logits enabled?
From a simple vanilla GAN code I look from GitHub
I saw this generator model with activation sigmoid:
# Generator
G = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(28*28 // 2, input_shape = (z_dim,), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(28*28, activation='sigmoid'),
  tf.keras.layers.Reshape((28, 28))])

The G's loss is defined like this where from_logits is enabled:
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits = True)
def G_loss(D, x_fake):
  return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(D(x_fake)), D(x_fake))

As far as I know, from_logits=True is intended to make loss function accept y_pred value that has range between -infinity to infinity. Opposite to from_logits=False where the loss function assume the value is range between 0 until 1.
As you see, the output layer of G model already has sigmoid activation where it's ranging between 0 until 1.
But, why the author still using from_logits=True?

The loss is for the discriminator, which does not have sigmoid in the output. It's used for the generator to force the output (images) to be in the range [0,1].

The author treats the output as probabilities. from_logits=True represent that the model outputs its values as probabilities. The range has nothing to do with the logits status. The sigmoid is what limits the output between 0 and 1. Logits=True in this case is means the author wants the outputs to be treated probabilities and not as as continuous values.

No, this is incorrect. logits are the pre-sigmoid values, so with sigmoid output the loss should take from_logits=False. True is for when one does not include the sigmoid function in the output layer.

The answer from David Demmers is wrong, as xdurch0 pointed out in the comment. This answer ist just for the sake of having a full answer with the solution in one place. Credits go to xdurch0.
You are correct that from_logits=True woul be wrong to use if the output layer for the loss function would use a sigmoid activation itself. But in the G_loss function, the loss is calculted on the output of the Discriminator:

def G_loss(D, x_fake):
  return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(D(x_fake)), D(x_fake))

Mind the bold text. The output of the Generator is indeed a probability, but the output of the Discriminator is not, because it uses no activation at the last layer. And for the loss of both the GEnerator and the Discriminator, the output of the Discriminator is used.
